# publishCreate - messages not broadcasted

Tags: sails.js

I stuck on publishCreate message broadcasting and have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Created a simple model called Sample:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        device: 'string',
        value: 'float'
    },

    afterCreate: function(sample, next) {
        console.log("afterCreate called");
        Sample.publishCreate({value: sample.value});
        console.log("publishCreate sent");
        next();
    }
};
```

Didnt find in the documentation if models do publishCreate automatically so I added afterCreate.

Then I created following view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/iphone.css">   
    <!-- Bring in the socket.io client -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
    <!-- then beef it up with some convenience logic for talking to Sails.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sails.io.js"></script>
    <!-- listen on socket.io for incoming messages -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        socket.on('message', function(msg){
            alert('message received');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block" style="height: 320px;">
        <div class="centered">
            <h1><%= temp %>°</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Theoretically now if I call the view in the browser and then in the other browser tab I call

```
http://localhost:1337/sample/create?device=AA&value=10.0
```

a message should be received on the client side in the above view but nothing happens.

I know from the messages that sockets are connected and publishCreate is called when new Sample is created.

What can be a reason? Do I also have to do something in the controller when calling res.view() ?

Comment: forgot to mention that in the controller method displaying the view in question I call `Sample.subscribe(req.socket);`

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful for an overview of socket.io and sails http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/09/15/episode-20-adding-real-time-events-to-models-in-4-lines-of-code/.

Comment: publishCreate is not working for me as well . 1) publishDestroy worked for me and to make sure my code is working fine I just replaced publishDestroy with publishCreate and then nothing broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

Did you explicitly declare your publishCreate in your create action of the controller?

```
'create': function(req,res,next){
  Sample.create(req.params.all(), function sampleCreated(err,sample){
    if(err){console.log(err); }
   Sample.publishCreate({
    id:sample.id,
    device: sample.device,
    value: sample.value
  });   
 });
},
```

You should probably explicitly declare the data points that you want to publish. Here I've set the Id, device, and value to be published explicitly. Blueprints and automatic controller mapping is useful, but it might be really unstable and unreliable sometimes, especially with the lack of documentation. Better to be specific.

Answer (score 2):

The likely problem here is that the controller action that contains the `subscribe` call is being run in response to an HTTP request, *not* a socket request.  `req.socket` is meaningless when the request is via HTTP; the server has no idea what socket was used.  In order for `subscribe` to work, the request has to be made over a socket connection, e.g. using the `socket.get` method in the `sails.io.js` library.

Answer (score 0):

we would need to use Model.watch(req) in order to subscribe to Model class. Then we will receive publishCreate() broadcasts.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/watch